# How to create diff of two generic T:Codable structs in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, generics, codable, runtime-type

**Given:** I have two structs of the same type, conforming to Codable Protocol. 
The structs can be multi-level (nested properties, surely also are conforming to Codable). The type is not known at the time of implementation, so i consider it generic, conforming to Codable.

One object is "base" (say, received from server), second (actually the copy of "base"), but modified inside application.

**The intention is:** To send a request for saving new data, but sending only the "diff" of two structs. So, only the fields, that are different should be present in resulting JSON.

The straightforward way with getting JSON strings for both structs and manipulating with them, is understandable, but seem to be the last-chance approach...

I've tried the approach with Mirror, and recursion, but now have managed to make it work only for first level - on the second level of nesting i've lost the type of nested property (if struct or array), and cannot cast it right then...

I wonder if it can be made somehow with custom encoder?

**P.S.:** the generic type should have all properties as Optionals, so should not provide any explicit initializers.

Comment: Is there any runtime benefit / performance boost requesting with only the ***modified fields*** over the ***modified object***? You could easily make the request with the ***modified object*** as a whole.

Comment: yes, actually, the request consists of several objects like this, and in real life it can be huge. So, it seem to be a benefit...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your "last-chance approach" -- matching JSON strings -- you could use `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` to convert the JSON data to Foundation objects and perform your comparison on that higher level of abstraction (if that's what you meant in your question in the first place, then sorry - nevermind).

Of course you'd pay an extra penalty of converting your `Codable` objects to data and then parsing that data into an object hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, actually, i did not mean to compare raw strings, but do smth like you suggest with JSONSerialization. But i wonder, if there is a "pure" Swift way to do this kind of job? It looks like to be a pretty common/ordinary task to do...

Comment: Ok I see. Yes it seems pretty common but as far as I know there's not "clean" way to do it with Swift... I'd be happy to be proven wrong by someone smarter though. One last idea that just came to my mind: there's a Sourcery template called Diffable (https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/blob/master/guides/Diffable.md) which is intended to be used in unit tests, but I think you could do something similar for business logic code: a Sourcery template to generate `diff` methods for your model objects which compare each property and produce a dictionary of changes.

Comment: yep, thanks for that link - looks pretty the way i've tried to do it at the very beginning - just getting some String-type diff result and, in my case, converting it to JSON "manually". But, for that moment, i agree with you, that no visible "clean" way to get the third structure of the given type from two original, containing the diff, not converting to-from JSON intermediately...